# CSS Hover Another element

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to target the .drop class when I hover on the .categories class, it is possible to do this with css only?

[image]

Comment: Nope. Also, please provide your code as text and not as an image ;)

Comment: no possible with `CSS` use `JS`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to affect other elements when a div is hovered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered)

Answer (score 3):

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float:left;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.categories:hover ~ .drop {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">categories</div>
<div class="drop">drop</div>
```

I am afraid you can not target an element that is up to the DOM relatively to the hovered element only with CSS. You can achieve this with jQuery like so:

```
$('.categories').hover(function() {
    $('.drop').css({ // your code }) 
});
```

If the HTML was something like this **check snippet**:

```
<div class="categories"></div>
<div class="drop"></div>
```

you could do this:

```
.categories:hover ~ .drop {
    /* css rules */
}
```